# How to rightly locate a value at an index in nd array and save it as list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a list called L. It has C number of elements.

I have a nd array called X. X has Boolean data (either 0 or 1). It has dimension as  (20,C). There are 20 lists with each list having C number of elements

I want to locate each index that has value of 1 in X.Then I want the value at this same index in List L, and finally store this value from L in another nd array .
I write the following code

`emptylist=[]`

`for index,value in np.ndenumerate(X):     #this index is a tuple like (0,3)`

```
tuple_to_list=list(i)
if value == 1:

   emptylist.append (L[tuple_to_list[1]])  #error
```

the program does not stop running. Can you guide me to improve this code ?

Answer (score 0):

the last line should be:

```
empylist.append(L[index[0]])
```

and I don't see what your tuple_to_list is needed for

A solution using only arrays would be the following:

```
L = list(np.random.rand(20)) # gives a List of radom values (to be compatible to the question)
La = np.array(L)
X = randint(0,5,(20,101)) # make an array having values from 0...4
emptylist = La[np.where(X==1)[0]] #gives those rows of L where rows of X contain 1
```

though the name empty is not appropriate anymore.

Comment: Since index is a tuple, I was converting to a list to access the second element. Can you  help me with the speed? It is taking very long to run it

Comment: you can also access the second element of a tuple without problem

Comment: how large is your array?

Comment: my array is (201 , 3438753 ). There are 201 lists , each having  3438753 elements

Comment: that is quite big, you will need several GB of RAM, nevertheless, I will propose a method using no for loop but numpy arrays. you might get into memory problems though

Comment: Any input is knowledge for me since i am a beginner, Please suggest your way . Thanks

Comment: I made a suggestion. Is the order important?

Comment: btw: my pc will freeze on the attempt because of the large size of the array you have. I propose to loop through smaller chunks of the same array to avoid memory overflow. The loop will then not cost much time anymore

Comment: Why is there a [0] in end ? I ran and it gives me a nd array which has each list with same element value repeating ..

Comment: Ok you have to be careful with the shapes of the arrays. Check that X.shape = (B, C) and La.shape = (B,). The [0] picks the first dimension (length B) similar to the for loop (there [1] was wrong and i corrected it)

Comment: I checked. X.shape = (B, C) and La.shape = (B,) is right in my code. Still I get all the list having a value repeated over

Comment: I modified my answer to be more expicit. Can you copy and paste and have a look how it behaves?

Comment: the repeating may happen if ones occur several times in the same row of X. I think this is expected. Would you prefer to iterate first along rows and then along columns (in contrast to the ndenumerate)