# How to get nd array from np.where() in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

My problem has different moving objects. We calculate distance between these objects in different time frame.

I have a nd array **A** with shape **(a,b)** which stores distances. a is the number of fames and b is the number of coordinates on which this distance is calculated.

I have a list **L** which has the names of these objects. It has a length of b.

I want to find where distance value is 1 . Then I want to locate the name of this index in list **L** (which has same index). I write the following

```
A=[[nd array]]
L=[list of names]
list_to_array=np.array(L)
array_of_names_meeting_criteria=list_to_array[np.where(A==1)[1]]
```

The problem is i am not getting names per frame. I want this array to be split frame wise so i get (a,x) where a is number of frames and for each frame I have x number of names

sample case

```
A=np.array[[1,2,2,6],[3,4,5,1],[3,1,17,4],[2,3,1,5]]
L=[('cat','dog'),('lion','elephant'),('man','women'),('fish','shark')]
llist_to_array=np.array(L)
array_of_names_meeting_criteria=list_to_array[np.where(A==1)[1]]
```

I should get the below :-

```
[['cat','dog'],['fish','shark'],['lion','elephant'],['man','women']]
```

Comment: Could you add a [`sample case`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Added, can you please check

Comment: You said - `"I have a nd array A with shape (a,b) "`. Your sample case seems to work with `A` as an array.

Comment: This is obviously a follow-up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345872/how-to-rightly-locate-a-value-at-an-index-in-nd-array-and-save-it-as-list-in-pyt  and it would be nice to either co accept answers there or continue the discussion

Comment: thanks for advising, since i am new to this website, i thought posting a new question when I think of a way of solving a problem but feel stuck( since discussions was from yesterday )

Comment: well as I said it's appreciated if you either accept answers (especially since you seem to use the proposed solution) or continue the discussion

Answer (score 0):

I just did some minor edits from your code and here's the result:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,2,6],[3,4,5,1],[3,1,17,4],[2,3,1,5]])
L = [('cat','dog'),('lion','elephant'),('man','women'),('fish','shark')]
list_to_array = np.array(L)
array_of_names_meeting_criteria = list_to_array[np.where(A==1)[1]]
```

Comment: did the modification work? I mean, the code i posted already gives the result that you wanted.